# One word for software systems with similar domain of functionality?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, terminology, american-english, synonyms

Synonyms are different words with similar meaning. Does there a word exist that denotes the same essence but denotes similar domain of functionality for different software systems.

For e.g. An internet bot and a desktop application which work with the English language to generate tweets and songs respectively. Irrespective of how they work since they both come under Natural Language Generation domain if one were to compare say both these systems and use a word `x` such that "Despite their commercial aspects both these systems are `x`.

P.S. I am not a native English speaker. Feel free to criticize as much on the writing style, grammar, and poor voice as well if any.

Comment: Both systems are natural language generation software.

Comment: You mean something like "word processors", "browsers", "defragmenters", "Image editors"?

Comment: @Mustafa Yes, most likely.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider the word **analogous** if you're looking for an adjective.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/analogous

> susceptible of comparison either in general or in some specific detail :  showing an analogy or a likeness that permits one to draw an analogy An airplane's joystick is somewhat analogous to the reins on a horse.

In your example:

> Both systems are analogous.

If you don't need an adjective, you could consider using the word **class** or **category**, or the word you used in your question, **domain**.

> Both systems are in the same **class** of software.
>
> Both systems are in the same software **domain**.

These aren't terms I've necessarily seen used in a field of technology exactly this way, but they would get your point across in communication.

Comment: +1 I like this answer. It gets to the heart of the structural similarity.

Answer (score 0):

The term I can think of is "**type**"

> **Type:** a number of things or persons sharing a particular
>   characteristic, or set of characteristics, that causes them to be
>   regarded as a group, more or less precisely defined or designated;
>   class; category

[Different / same types of software](http://web2.uvcs.uvic.ca/elc/sample/ite/u01/u1_1_03.html)

[Types of software](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A-level_Computing/CIE/Computer_systems,_communications_and_software/Components_of_a_computer_system_and_modes_of_use/Types_of_software)

Answer (score 0):

Despite their commercial aspects both these systems are **using the same architecture**.

> **Software architecture** refers to the high level structures of a software system, the discipline of creating such structures, and the documentation of these structures. These structures are needed to reason about the software system. Each structure comprises software elements, relations among them, and properties of both elements and relations. The architecture of a software system is a metaphor, analogous to the architecture of a building.
>   - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_architecture

Also **pattern** or **design** etc may work